# Data Virtualization connection to Azure Data Lake Store Gen1 - WebHDFS/v1/ endpoint

Tags: odata, azure-data-lake, webhdfs, data-virtualization

I'm trying to configure **Azure Data Lake Store Gen1 (ADLS)** as a **Data Source** in a Data Virtualization software (Tibco's).

Reading through the Azure documentation, I got to the **webhdfs/v1/** endpoint associated with ADLS and managed to simulate the (non-standard, since it requieres an additional "resource" parameter) OAuth2 authentication needed within Postman. All good so far.

I am guessing that the connection should be configured as an OData service, since the OData connector within TDV (Tibco DV) has an "Azure AD resource" parameter that should be used only if you are trying to authenticate through azure's active directory (the non-standard part from before). However I am failing to configure this connection.

This must be because of one of these reasons:

1. The /webhdfs/v1/ endpoint is NOT an OData service.
2. I am wrongly configuring the OData connector in TDV.

In any case, **how can I connect to this repository and introspect everything behind it?** list folders, files, and all that within TDV?

Some suggestions I have stumbled upon are using the Hive connectors or the REST connector, but after trying I still feel closer to success with OData.